# TSQL Xpath Modify XML string

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures, xpath

I am trying to modify an XML string to replace the value of a node with something else. The end goal will be mass encrypting account numbers in a column but for the time being, I'm just trying to replace the one in the XML string.

When I execute this, I get "Command completed successfully" even though I am trying to return data.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><account>155555555</account></optional>'


SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/optional/account/text())[1] with "' + (
              SELECT 'ABC-' + ParamValues.item.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
              FROM @xml.nodes('/optional/account') AS ParamValues(item)
       )+ '"')

SELECT @xml
```

Any thoughts as to why this isn't replacing the account number in the XML string with the `ABC-Account Number Here` and returning it?

Comment: I don't know what `SET @xml.modify...` is meant to do, but what it is doing is stopping the process in its tracks. If you replace `SELECT @xml` with `SELECT 1`, you get the same result. If you're trying to replace the content of the XML tag with all that text, I think you'll have to compose it as a string and then create some whole new XML.

Comment: Well if I take out the inner select and just replace it with some text I type in, it works perfectly fine resetting the @XML var with the next value. However when you try and update it dynamically from another select statement, it runs into the issue

Comment: `SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/optional/account/text())[1] with concat("ABC-", (/optional/account)[1])')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question, "why isn't it replacing the account number", it's because XML function parameters must be string literals. You are constructing the parameter to the `modify` XML function, which is causing an error condition.

Normally, SQL Server throws an error when you aren't using a string literal in your XML function parameter, but in this case, it must be confused because of the `nodes()` function call.

Here is a simple example with a string literal which works, as you point out in your comment:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><account>155555555</account></optional>'
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/optional/account/text())[1] with "1"');
SELECT @xml;
```

However, if you try to construct the `modify` XML function parameter, as in the below example, it will fail:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><account>155555555</account></optional>'
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/optional/account/text())[1] with "' + '1' + '"');
SELECT @xml;
```

The error is:

> Msg 8172, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The argument 1 of the XML data
>   type method "modify" must be a string literal.

Apparently, if you get a little fancier by throwing the `nodes()` in there, it confuses SQL Server and squelches the error condition:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><account>155555555</account></optional>'
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/optional/account/text())[1] with "' + (SELECT '1' FROM @xml.nodes('/optional/')) + '"');
SELECT @xml;
```

That doesn't error, but rather terminates before displaying any data and simply prints:

> Command(s) completed successfully.

So you can't really construct the XML function parameter. However, you can still use outside information. Kiran Hedge [showed how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30925563/2266979) by using the `sql:variable()` [XQuery extension function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186364.aspx).

However, you don't actually have to go to that length. You are using data from inside the XML, which the XML processor has native access to. So you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @newXmlSingleReplacement XML = '<optional><account>155555555</account></optional>';
SET @newXmlSingleReplacement.modify('replace value of ((/optional/account)/text())[1] with fn:concat("ABC-",((/optional/account)/text())[1])');
SELECT @newXmlSingleReplacement;
```

So either Kiran's or this solution works fine for your simplified example. But you probably have a more complex XML document. It probably has multiple "rows" which you'd like to change.

If you try the same code from above with an XML document with multiple account numbers, only the first number is replaced:

```
DECLARE @newXmlSingleReplacement XML ='<optional><account>155555555</account></optional><optional><account>255555555</account></optional>';
    SET @newXmlSingleReplacement.modify('replace value of ((/optional/account)/text())[1] with fn:concat("ABC-",((/optional/account)/text())[1])');
    SELECT @newXmlSingleReplacement;
```

Results:

```
<optional>
  <account>ABC-155555555</account>
</optional>
<optional>
  <account>255555555</account>
</optional>
```

You might think you could simply remove the index ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30925563/2266979)) and affect all of the rows. Unfortunately, according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675(v=sql.105).aspx), the first parameter of `replace value of` "must identify only a single node". So you can't take a list of all of the account numbers and operate on that.

This example:

```
DECLARE @newXmlSingleReplacement XML ='<optional><account>155555555</account></optional><optional><account>255555555</account></optional>';
SET @newXmlSingleReplacement.modify('replace value of ((/optional/account)/text()) with fn:concat("ABC-",((/optional/account)/text()))');
SELECT @newXmlSingleReplacement;
```

Results in this error:

> Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 XQuery [modify()]: 'concat()'
>   requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type
>   'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

So instead, you could loop over all of your "rows" and perform the `modify()` operation each time. You would need a way to track your progress with a counter. Here is an example of that, using slightly more complex XML to prove up the concept.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><other>Test123</other><account>155555555</account></optional><optional><other>Test321</other><account>255555555</account></optional>';
DECLARE @newxml XML = @xml, @AccountCount int = 0, @Counter int = 0;
SET @AccountCount = @newxml.value('fn:count(//account)','int');
WHILE @Counter <= @AccountCount
BEGIN
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
    SET @newxml.modify('replace value of ((/optional/account)[position()=sql:variable("@Counter")]/text())[1] with fn:concat("ABC-",((/optional/account)[position()=sql:variable("@Counter")]/text())[1])');
END
SELECT  @newxml;
```

Results:

```
<optional>
  <other>Test123</other>
  <account>ABC-155555555</account>
</optional>
<optional>
  <other>Test321</other>
  <account>ABC-255555555</account>
</optional>
```

Of course we would prefer to avoid loops in SQL code, if we can. Single statements which operate on sets often yield better performance.

One option is to shred your XML and reform it, while adjusting the values in the process. The disadvantage of this method is that you must know the specifics of the XML in order to reconstruct it. It might also be an expensive and convoluted statement, depending on the complexity of the XML document. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><other>Test123</other><account>155555555</account></optional><optional><other>Test321</other><account>255555555</account></optional>';
SELECT
    v.value('(./other)[1]','varchar(500)') AS other,
    'ABC-' + v.value('(./account)[1]','varchar(500)') AS account
FROM        @xml.nodes('/optional') AS T(v)
FOR XML PATH ('optional'), TYPE;
```

But that's not the only way to reform the XML. You could reconstruct it using the XML system itself and its [FLWOR statement support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945(v=sql.105).aspx). For example:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><other>Test123</other><account>155555555</account></optional><optional><other>Test321</other><account>255555555</account></optional>';
SELECT @xml.query ('
    for $optional in //optional
    return
        <optional>
            {$optional/other}
            <account>ABC-{$optional/account/text()}</account>
        </optional>

');
```

But again, that requires knowing and manually recreating the structure of the XML. There are ways to avoid that. The next example requires minimal knowledge of the existing XML. It essentially loops over the nodes at the level of the account node and replaces them only if they are named "account".

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><other>Test123</other><account>155555555</account></optional><optional><other>Test321</other><account>255555555</account></optional>';
SELECT @xml.query ('
    for $optional in //optional
    return
        <optional>
            {
                for $subnode in $optional/*
                    return
                        if (fn:local-name($subnode) = "account")
                        then    
                            <account>ABC-{$subnode/text()}</account>
                        else
                            $subnode
            }
        </optional>
');
```

Based on a crude test with `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` on these very small example XML documents, it appears that the `nodes()` shredding and reconstructing is slightly faster. It also has the simplest and lowest cost query plan by a significant margin.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot replace the value with another select statement. You can only use sql variable for dynamic values as below

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<optional><account>155555555</account></optional>';
DECLARE @val VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @val ='ABC-' + @xml.value('(/optional/account/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/optional/account/text())[1] with sql:variable("@val")');
SELECT  @xml;
```

Comment: So then I guess a shift in thought here.. Lets just say I wanted to search the column in the table called `details`. In that column, it contains an XML string like above where the account numbers are all different. I need to replace that value with the `ABC-Existing Value Here`